# Different ways of getting JSON data from website

Tags: python, json, url

Here are four approaches to get information written in JSON from the URL:

1. Working:

```
response = requests.get(URL)
response = response.json()
```

2. Error (`TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Response`):

```
response = requests.get(URL)
response = json.loads(response)
```

3. Error (`TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Response`):

```
response = requests.get(URL)
response = json.load(response)
```

4. Error (`AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'read'`):

```
response = requests.get(URL)
response = response.read()
```

I found that 2., 3., 4. are not working. Why?

What does `request.get()` return? And how can I turn JSON into dictionary form? I want to know other ways different from 1.

```
response = requests.get(URL)
print(response.text)
```

Code above also printed data in string type, so I wonder what 'response' object is.

Comment: Both codes in 1 and 3 are the same?

Comment: @HarshanaSerasinghe I editted it.

Comment: @buran oh that would work. What is difference between '''load''' and '''loads'''? And Is 'docs' a form of information?

Comment: docs stands for documentation. that's exactly where you need to look for the difference between [json.load()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) and [json.loads()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads)

Comment: @buran thanks!!! Could you recommend me materials for studying about docs?

Comment: Not sure what's there to study about documentation. Python has it's official documentation, every decent package should be well-documented. And normally that would be the first place to consult when in doubt about how thinks work or what the interface is.